# Simple Deform modifier not working as expected

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

I'd like to bend this mesh into a curve. Basically almost like a U shape. I've set an empty to be the origin of the modifier but the result is skewed. Its like as if its being twisted. I just want it bent.
[image]
Any suggestions on how to bend this?

More detail on the shape i want :
[image]
Its a switch and i would like it to follow the curvature of the large object.

Here's the file to this specific part [image]

Comment: hello, maybe show you would like your object to be bent and share your file?

Comment: Just uploaded it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to align the empty orientation with the object orientation: Select the empty, shift select the object, go into the N panel and right click into the *Rotation* values > *Copy All to Selected*:

[image]

Now rotate the empty 90° on its own X axis (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> 90) and play with the *SimpleDeform Angle* value until you're good:

[image]